# Gnuplot plotting the wrong graph from given datapoints

Tags: gnuplot

I have a file containing some datapoints:

```
# energytime.dat
# X Y
64.934 1993
64.9264 0.0029
64.9022 1897
64.9296 1877
64.8698 1885
64.953 3799
```

I wrote the following script to plot a graph:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist
set title "Energy vs. Time for all algorithms"
set xlabel "Energy"
set ylabel "Time"
set style line 1 \
    linecolor rgb '#0060ad' \
    linetype 1 linewidth 2 \
    pointtype 7 pointsize 1.5
plot "energytime.dat" with linespoints linestyle 1
pause -1 "Hit Enter to continue"
```

This gives the following graph:
[image: wrong graph]

It is obvious that this plot is wrong. What modifications should I make to my script to get the correct graph?

Comment: Why is this plot "wrong"? Your command simply plots your data in the sequence of the data lines connected with lines and points. What plot do you expect and would consider as "correct"? Please show a sketch.

Answer (score 0):

As @theozh wrote, gnuplot simply plots the data in the order they stored in the datafile. However, you can "correct" your graph with `smooth unique`

```
plot "energytime.dat" smooth unique with linespoints linestyle 1
```

(assuming, that you will never have two identical x values).

[image: good result]

**NOTE**

It is important, to use `smooth unique` before `with`.